# If a group of people share individual de minimis sections of a copyrighted work, sufficient to reconstruct the work, is this copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright, any-jurisdiction

Suppose a group of people share small segments of a copyrighted work in a chat room. If the song "Amazing Grace" were still under copyright, it could go something like this:

```
<A> Amazing grace...
<B> ...how sweet...
<C> ...the sound...
<D> ...that saved...
[and so on]
<Y> ...but now...
<Z> ...I see.
```

If each line is sent by a different person, have they collectively infringed copyright? They are deliberately posting a copyrighted song; they are not independently writing a song that happens to be the same as an existing one.

Comment: Did they each create their snippets without having been previously exposed to the original?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite no, they're deliberately basing it on the original.

Answer (score 2):

The gang has infringed copyright. The court-made *de minimis* doctrine would not be applicable here since the amount copied is the entire work, not a trivial amount. In no case has the doctrine been applied to immunize conspirators who serially copy a work against liability for infringement.

Comment: My question would be how did they become a gang?  If the above exchange occurred spontaneously among people who had not previous interacted would that still be a gang?

Comment: @User65535 they became a conspiracy to commit copyright by agreeing, as the first person started the song, to continue and sing it in total.